# convert array of string to array of object - javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of strings. 
`["A", "B", "C", "D"]`

How can I add a key to the array, to make it object.

Like this, to an array on object.

`[{ id: "A" }, { id: "B" }, { id: "C" }]`

I tried the following:

```
const newArray = this.myArray.map(function(item) {
    return 'id:' + item;
 });
```

This does not work for me though.

Comment: you are returning a string, not an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track. You're returning a string. You must return an object

```
const newArray = this.myArray.map(function(item) {
   return {'id': item};
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside the `map()` event handler function you are returning a string not an object. You should form the object and return that.

You can also achieve that in a single line with arrow function (`=>`):

```js
const myArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
const newArray = myArray.map(i => ({id: i}));
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just return an object instead of a string:

```js
const arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
const res = arr.map(id => ({id}));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use-case for [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const stringArr = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

const objArr = stringArr.map(id => ({ id }));

console.log(objArr);
```